# How to return rows as much as column in table MySql

Tags: mysql

I have one table there are many records. When I select the record by id then I need the result in the row as per column.

```
Table  
ID         field1             field2
1          name1              picture1
```

**Output like:-**

```
ID         field1            
1          name1             
1          picture1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a `UNION`:

```
(SELECT ID, field1 FROM yourtable)
UNION
(SELECT ID, field2 FROM yourtable)
ORDER BY ID
```

If you have more than two fields, you would extend the sequence of `UNION/SELECT` to cover them all. If you want to only get data for a specific `ID` value (e.g. 1), add a `WHERE` clause to each `SELECT`:

```
(SELECT ID, field1 FROM yourtable WHERE ID=1)
UNION
(SELECT ID, field2 FROM yourtable WHERE ID=1)
ORDER BY ID
```

Comment: Thank you for help